# yarn install removing few packages

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I used yarn install to install few packages. Below are the dependencies.

```
@types/node
@types/react
@types/react-dom
```

When I add any of these packages, it is removing the other two. Not sure why is it happening. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a bit more context, what commands are you running to install? Are the packages in package.json?

Comment: Yarn can add multiple packages at the same time, does `yarn add -D @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom` work for you?

Comment: @Qurben I have the packages in my package.json. I am using yarn install in the same directory as the package.json. I also have yarn.lock file which is resolved as per my repository settings. yarn add -D worked, thank you. But why is it not installing properly when I try yarn install?

Comment: Yarn install does try to tidy the package.json file, so it might be that your dependencies are already in there or that yarn moves them in the list. Check `node_modules` or `.yarn/cache` to see if the package shows up to check if it actually worked.